# Popup UIPickerview when button is pressed

Tags: iphone

Is there something wrong with this code because when i press the button to pop up the  `UIPickerview`.  Nothing happens. Why is that

```
  -(void)pickerview:(id)sender
{
items =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hindi",@"English",nil];

pickerView=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,100,150,150)];

pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75f, 0.75f);

pickerView.delegate = self;

pickerView.dataSource = self;

pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[pickerView selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{

return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{

return [items count];   
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

return[items objectAtIndex:row];

}
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yeah.. big problem ..

```
[self.view addSubview:pickerview];
```

is missing

also are you sure your button press is calling this method..it returns (`void`) .. if connected to xib component it should show `IBAction`

Comment: Thanks a lot how i can add background wall of grey color

Comment: background wall ? ..didn't understand that.. play with this code in your code..`pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
`

Comment: that is fine i got it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: how do you resign it once option has been selected?